# Region of uniform convergence

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, functional-calculus

I have to find the region of uniform convergence of

### $$e^{x} +2^p\,e^{-2x} +3^p\,e^{−3x} +4^p\,e^{-4x} +\cdots $$

Should I start by saying that the expression is less or larger than a value?

Comment: You should start by editing your question using using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Lol what is this edit?

Comment: I wrote something wrong from the beginning but ok I will write it as it was

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** $\displaystyle\frac{(n+1)^pe^{-(n+1)x}}{n^pe^{-nx}}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)^pe^{-x}$.

Comment: Thank you but how can i continue with that?

Comment: It follows from what I wrote, from the ratio test and from the Weierstrass $M$-test that the series converges uniformly on every interval $[a,\infty)$, with $a>0$.

Comment: How did you find that you wrote me in the hint? and also i do not have to say that the expression i have is less than a number and show that converges? thank you

Comment: I found the formula that I gave you doing the computations. And now, in $[a,\infty)$, we have$$\left\lvert\frac{(n+1)e^{-(n+1)x}}{n^pe^{-nx}}\right\rvert\leqslant\left(1+\frac1n\right)^pe^{-a}$$and, since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^p=1$,$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^pe^{-a}<e^{-a/2}<1,$$if $n$ is large enough.

Comment: so is this the region of uniform convergence ?

Comment: There is no such thing as **the** region of uniform convergence. *Each* interval of $[a,\infty)$ is a region of uniform convergence.

Answer (score 1):

From $x\leq 0$ we have $\sum_{k=1}^\infty k^p e^{-kx}\geq \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^p=+\infty$ (assuming $p\geq-1$; for a  general $p \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x>0$ you can show that $a_k$ does not tend to 0). In case $x>\epsilon>0$ we can apply the M-test with $M_{k,\epsilon}=k^p e^{-k \epsilon}$, and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty M_{k,\epsilon}<\infty$ via ratio test.

So the series converge uniformly in $I_\epsilon=(\epsilon,+\infty)$ for any $\epsilon >0$.

**Edit**: Note that in case $ p<-1$ we can set $\epsilon=0 $ and obtaining uniform convergence in $[0,+\infty)$ using $M_{0,k}$.

Comment: I understand that but i think it is not enough

Comment: What is not enough? This proves that the region of uniform convergence is $I_\epsilon$ and it's also maximal. For $\sum M_{k,\epsilon}<\infty $ you can use the ration test that works as in the answer of @JoséCarlosSantos shows.

Comment: I think that i also have to use Cauchy test..

Comment: Cauchy test is equivalent to uniform convergence, but if the M-test (that is a  sufficient condition) already works, and elsewhere the series does not even converge pointwise, you don't need to invoke that characterization.

Comment: I asked my teacher and told me for hint that i also have to use cauchy test but i do not know how to..

Comment: Btw thank you for your effort